# SQLite cursor returning IllegalStateException?

Tags: android, cursor

I am trying to add elements to a DB and then search for a particular entry. But I get a cursor error. Here is my code for the DB class. The database contains only a single column. Thanks in advance.

```
public class DataB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String db_name = "testing.db";
    private static final int version = 1;
    private static final String table_name = "students";
    private static final String col_name="FirstName";
    public DataB(Context context) {
        super(context, db_name, null, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String q = "CREATE TABLE " + table_name + " (FirstName TEXT PRIMARY KEY) ";
        db.execSQL(q);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+table_name);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public int addData(String name)
    {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(col_name, name);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(table_name, null, cv);
        db.close();
        return 1;
    }
    public String search(String string)
    {
        String dbstring=" ";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM "+ table_name + " WHERE FirstName = '" + string+"'";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        while(!c.isAfterLast())
        {
            if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FirstName"))!=null)
            {
                dbstring = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FirstName"));
            }
        }
        return dbstring;
    }
}
```

The error is 
    `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn\'t read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.`

Comment: What are you trying to acchieve? why the following  while(!c.isAfterLast()) ?

Comment: That was to check if the cursor is not pointing beyond the last row!

Comment: @Vishal did you change any columns in the database and run this? If you did make any changes to the database, first increment the database version and try running the app.

Comment: getColumnIndex is returning "-1". According to docs, that column was not found.. that's why it returns -1. Do what Dinesh mentioned: if you create that column recently, update Database version (or unistall/install de app again) to create the database with that new column.

Comment: or add a protection and call only getString() if getColumnIndex >= 0;

Comment: @DineshBob Thank You! The solution eliminated the error but the app is stuck!

Comment: "app is stuck" - sorry, explain a bit more.

Comment: On clicking the search button, the app freezes.

Comment: if(c != null) { while(c.moveToNext()) { ...... } }

Comment: use this. instead of your while loop.

Comment: @DineshBob while will he loop if he is always updating the string dbstring ?

Comment: yes. as @JpCrow said. your while loop is infinite. you are just asking isAfterLast(), and not iterating the cursor.

Comment: Yeah! Thank you guys!

Comment: his assumption is there will be only one row in the cursor. yes, while loop is not necessary in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while is not working at all you are never changing the cursor position so it will always be true making a stackoverflow

After performing your query you should ask if the cursor is not null and if can move to first position, like the following:

```
    if(c != null && c.moveToFirst()){      
       dbstring = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(col_name));           
     }
```

Or in your case because the only column you have is FirstName you can look it like this:

```
    if(c != null && c.moveToFirst()){      
       dbstring = c.getString(0);           
    }
```

Remember that if you change anything in your database you should upgrade the database version.